# What happening to my garlic to make these stems mushy?

Tags: garlic

It's been an odd year for my hardneck garlic in zone 4b.

There's been some discolouring on the leaves which I think is mostly rust or lack of moisture. Some very dried leafs that look like they have been fried by the sun. But I can't wrap my head around what's causing these leaves/early scapes to become completely mushy and moist.

I found a singular bug on my whole 40ish patch, I've never even seen a bug on garlic before. Any ideas how to rally my plants before harvest?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Definitely leafminers. Took another look today and there's a lot more of these bugs. Black dots, larvae and grubs on the inside of stems. I've done some pruning and put together [this](https://www.finegardening.com/article/garlic-and-chile-insecticidal-soap-spray#:%7E:text=Put%20the%20garlic%2C%20chiles%2C%20and,with%20sediment%20in%20the%20bottom.) mixture of garlic, chilli and washing liquid which I will apply tomorrow to keep it in check. Hoping they'll rebound in the coming weeks as we're about a month away from harvest tops.

Comment: Good luck, and thank you for coming back with an answer.